# Link roto en mensaje de cambio de reputación

Tags: bug, estado-completado, perfil, enlaces

Cuando uno ve su propio perfil de usuario, si no hay cambios de reputación, aparece un mensaje con un link a `/help/whats-reputation`.
Actualmente ese link está roto, producto de la tracción al español (supongo).

[image: cambio de reputación]

Espero que pueda ser analizado y corregido, creo que el markdown del link debería ser así:

`No tienes ningún [cambio de reputación positiva](/help/whats-reputation)`

Nota: según lo que pudo ver @lois6b, si el perfil es de otro usuario, mensaje que se muestra tiene el link correctamente armado:

[image: perfil de otro usuario]

Comment: Listo. Se ha corregido esto.  Hay que darle unas cuantas horas para que tome efecto. :)

Comment: Eso es eficiencia @JuanM :)